# Linear gradient is showing two colors despite only one being specified

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to understand how a linear gradient with only one color specified is producing a background with two different colors.

```css
.book-bg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #24ab9d
  linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      #238d82 16px,
      rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) 16px,
      rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) 100%
    )
}
```

```html
<div class="book-bg"></div>
```

I would expect this linear gradient to produce a background with only `#238d82`. The rgba value (`rgba(35, 141, 130, 0)`) converts to the same hex code so shouldn't this div just be one color? What is causing the dark strip at the top?

Comment: Your background color is `#24ab9d` and linear-gradient starts from 16px down.

Comment: `rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) != #238d82` - the former is completely transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the `#24ab9d` that you defined to be the background-color layer. Your code is equialent to this one:

```css
.book-bg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( to bottom, #238d82 16px, rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) 16px, rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) 100%);
  background-color: #24ab9d;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-bg"></div>
```

Or this one since you are considering transparent color:

```css
.book-bg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( to bottom, #238d82 16px, transparent 16px);
  background-color: #24ab9d;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-bg"></div>
```

Also the same as:

```css
.book-bg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( to bottom, #238d82 16px, #24ab9d 16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="book-bg"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Temani! That is very helpful. Do you know why the middle value is necessary (rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) 16px)? Isn't this just hiding behind the first value (#238d82 16px)?

Comment: @cjk47 the middle value is necessary to have the color stop there ... a gradient is to have a fading color .. if you omit the middle value you will have a fading from 16px to 100% ... by setting this middle point you explicitely said you will have the same color from 16px to 100% (remove it to see wha is happening)

Comment: @cjk47 I would probably say that the last value is not necessary and you only need the two first (like in my last example)

Comment: @cjk47 more details about the value can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071464/8620333

Answer (score 1):

```
.book-bg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #24ab9d
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      #238d82 0px,
      rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) 16px,
      rgba(35, 141, 130, 0) 100%
    );
}
```

> Start colour of a linear gradient function is starting from 16px because of which you are seeing a dark strip at the top.