# border-image-source: linear-gradient only reading one color

Tags: css

I am trying to create a border gradient effect like the below:

[image]

I have the below, but for whatever reason the second color is not being read, alas the border just renders a plain white without a gradient effect, and this is on chrome/mac. Any suggestions or known quirk?

```
  input { 
     height: 40px;
     padding: 8px 93px 13px 18px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 2px;
     border-image-source: linear-gradient(294deg, #fff 105%, #68d9d5 71%, #68d9d5 71%);
     border-image-slice: 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current linear gradient is white in all of the visible area.

It does this because the gradient generated by `#fff 105%, #68d9d5 71%, #68d9d5 71%` goes:

- Between 0-105%: #fff (As 0% is not defined, the first color passed in is used)
- Between 105-71%: #68d9d5

Slightly unintuitively, the colors that come first end up on top (of the visibility stack) of the gradient, so the 105-71% range is hidden behind the initial white area.

Replacing it with `linear-gradient(95deg, #68d9d5 71%, #fff 100%);` will provide closer results.

```css
body {
  background-color: #0E2B47;
}

input {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 93px 13px 18px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(95deg, #68d9d5 71%, #fff 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: awesome, thanks bruh

Comment: *so the 105-71% range is hidden* --> not really like that, you cannot have overlapping ranges. Any small value will get clamped to the biggest one from the last range. So the browser will transform the 71% into 105%. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071464/8620333 *If a color stop has a position that is less than the specified position of any color stop before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color stop before it.*